# Empty test suite and custom package name

Tags: android, junit, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-espresso

I have an app with flavorDimensions and productFlavors and I am customising the package name of Trial variants with the build.gradle script as follows:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        def flavorString = variant.getVariantData().getVariantConfiguration().getFlavorName();
        if(flavorString.endsWith("Trial")) {
            def mergedFlavour = variant.getVariantData().getVariantConfiguration().getMergedFlavor();
            mergedFlavour.setApplicationId(mergedFlavour.getApplicationId().concat("trial"))
        }
    }
}
```

Everything works fine but when I try to run my test cases against Trial variants I get the message:

```
Running tests
Test running startedFinish
Empty test suite.
```

I can run the tests against other variants perfectly, but I would like to know how to fix this situation.

Before anyone suggest to use applicationIdSuffix in buildType, I don't think that suits this case, I need to add a suffix to variants.

This is the build.gradle script for flavorDimensions and productFlavors:

```
flavorDimensions "merchant", "version"

productFlavors {
     merchant1 {
        flavorDimension "merchant"
        applicationId "com.merchant1"
     }
     merchant2 {
        flavorDimension "merchant"
        applicationId "com.merchant2"
     }

     trial {
        flavorDimension "version"
     }
     prod {
        flavorDimension "version"
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can now set applicationIdSuffix for productFlavors:

```
android {  
     productFlavors {  
          free {   
               applicationIdSuffix = ".free"  
          }  
          prod {

          } 
     }  
}
```

Source:
http://android-developers.blogspot.ie/2015/12/leveraging-product-flavors-in-android.html